# Image summaries with TensorFlow's Dataset API

Tags: api, tensorflow, dataset, summary, tensorboard

I am using [TensorFlow's Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) to load and preprocess images. I would like to add summaries of my preprocessed images to Tensorboard.

What is the recommended way to do this?

So far, my code looks like this:

```py
def get_data():
  dataset = FixedLengthRecordDataset(...)
  dataset = dataset.map(dataset_parser, ...)
  if is_training:
    dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_for_train, ...)
  # Do shuffling, batching...
  return dataset

def preprocess_for_train(image, label):
  # Do preprocessing...
  image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
  # Add summary
  tf.summary.image('preprocessed_image', tf.expand_dims(image, 0))
  return image, label
```

Within `preprocess_for_train` my image is listed in the `SUMMARIES` collection, but it is no longer part of the graph when returning to the outer function. I think this happens because `map` uses a different thread and therefore refers to a different instance of `tf.Graph`.

Since this is not working, what other options do I have to display my images in Tensorboard?

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack to add the preprocessed images to Tensorboard, using the output of my iterator:

```py
train_dataset = get_data()
iterator = Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types, train_dataset.output_shapes)
# Batch consists of [image, label]
next_batch = iterator.get_next()
tf.summary.image('preprocessed_image', next_batch[0])
```

However, this will call next_batch a second time when running the summary_op. It helps for just debugging the image preprocessing, but it is not a solution for real training. Furthermore, only the fully preprocessed images can be observed, not intermediate preprocessing stages.